# Replace comma delimited file with pipe, but not remove comma or quotes etc within text qualifier field, however, remove text qualifier!

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, replace

My file is a comma delimited file and text qualifier is ~, but my requirement is to find and replace comma delimited file with |(pipe) delimited file and remove text qualifier ~ with nothing, however,
I should not remove quote or double quotes or any special character within the data present in text qualifier. eg: ~abc",~   I need it as abc",

Below is the content of my source file and the way i expect the output or manipulated file to be.

Source file:

```
364034,2015652205,26722,2015,4,~C25753-4~,~TC25753,~,~2WD Double Cab 144.2" SLT,~,~Y~,40506.16,43555.00,1095.00,~043,005,006,007,003,008,016,041,012,029,068,027,028,033~,3,~2WD Double Cab 144.2"~,~SLT~,6,4,~N~,~S~,~N~,~S~,~N~,~N~,~N~,~~,~ ~,~Confirmed~,~w2015k65m22t5~,~Sierra 2500HD~,~Double Cab Standard Box 2-Wheel Drive SLT~,~Rear Wheel Drive~,~Extended Cab Pickup - Standard Bed~
```

After cleansing I need the file like this:

```
364034|2015652205|26722|2015|4|C25753-4|TC25753,|2WD Double Cab 144.2" SLT,|Y|40506.16|43555.00|1095.00|043|005|006|007|003|008|016|041|012|029|068|027|028|033|3|2WD Double Cab 144.2"|SLT|6|4|N|S|N|S|N|N|N|| |Confirmed|w2015k65m22t5|Sierra 2500HD|Double Cab Standard Box 2-Wheel Drive SLT|Rear Wheel Drive|Extended Cab Pickup - Standard Bed
```

I tried sed -i -e with multiple options but the output is not 100% right.

I tried following but it's not giving right result that i wanted

```
sed -i -e 's/,~/|/g' file_name
sed -i -e 's/~,/|/g' file_name
sed -i -e 's/~//g' file_name
sed -i -e 's/\([0-9],[0-9]\)/|/g' file_name
sed -i -e 's/\r//g' file_name
```

Comment: format your question to make it  readable

Comment: How about `tr -d '~' <file | tr -s ',' '|'`, or sed equivalent `sed 's/~//g;s/,\+/|/g' file`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi There, I am looking for basically replacing , with | ( but not when these are enclosed within ~abc,#~) then finally remove text qualifier ~

Input file is like:
1234,4826,~Ter1337,#~,~~,~46437uyy"@~

Desired manipulated input file
1234|4826|Ter1337,#||46437uyy"@

Answer (score 2):

```
ESC=$(printf '\033')
RED="${ESC}[0;31m"
 NC="${ESC}[0m"

sed -e '
   /./!b
   /[^[:space:]]/!b

   s/.*/\
&,/

   :loop
      h
      s/\(\n\),/|\1/;                                                  # An empty field
      s/\(\n\)\([+-]\{0,1\}[.][0-9]\{1,\}\),/\2|\1/;                   # +-.NNN
      s/\(\n\)\([+-]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\([.][0-9]*\)\{0,1\}\),/\2|\1/;  # +-NNN.MMM +-NNN. +-NNN
      s/\(\n\)~\([0-9][0-9]*\),/\2|\1/;                                # ~NNN
      s/\(\n\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)~,/\2|\1/;                                # NNN~
      s/\(\n\)~\([^~]*\)~,/\2|\1/;                                     # ~...~
      x;G
      /^\(.*\)\n\1$/{
         g;'"s/\n\([^,]*\)/${RED}\1${NC}/"'
         i\
***'"${RED}ERROR${NC}"'*** Unable to process the field shown colored.\
\
Cause of error: What this means is that this particular field is not \
\
           Fix: You should add to the sed code in the :loop label to \
                digest the able to be processed by the sed code as it stands.\
\
The record with the offending field shown colored red:\

         q
      }
      g; # all clear: recover and carry on...
   /\n$/!bloop

   s/..$//
' csv.data
```

---

### Working

- We base the solution on the various types of fields.
- Skip empty or blank lines.
- Append a "," to simplify regex used, we'll take it away at the end.
- To set the ball rolling we place a marker, `\n`, at the beginning of line. This marker will travel from left to right, jumping a field processed a time.
- The action begins in the `do-while` loop, in the body of which, we process a field at a time. The field beginning is signaled by `\n` and we process the various varieties of fields that can occur. Everytime, we bring the field processed away to the left of `\n` and replace the `,` by a `|`.
- The looping stops when the marker `\n` hits the end of line `/\n$/` and we then take away the marker as well as the dummy `,` we had placed in the beginning.

---

### Results

```
364034|2015652205|26722|2015|4|C25753-4|TC25753,|2WD Double Cab 144.2" SLT,|Y|40506.16|43555.00|1095.00|043|005|006|007|003|008|016|041|012|029|068|027|028|033|3|2WD Double Cab 144.2"|SLT|6|4|N|S|N|S|N|N|N|| |Confirmed|w2015k65m22t5|Sierra 2500HD|Double Cab Standard Box 2-Wheel Drive SLT|Rear Wheel Drive|Extended Cab Pickup - Standard Bed
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks much for replying quickly. I incorporated the logic you provided in a Shell script which is supposed to perform the task explained for multiple files in a directory. Following is the shell script and when I execute the code it gets stuck on First file execution without performing anything. Can you please check and provide any suggestions to address the issue?

Comment: Here is the shell script
#!/bin/ksh
cd /CustomFolder/input/Test
FILES=$(ls -t *.txt)
for f in $FILES
do
sed -e '
   # skip empty and blank lines
   /./!b
   /[^[:space:]]/!b

   s/$/,/
   G;s/\(.*\)\(.\)/\2\1/

   :loop
      s/\(\n\),/|\1/
      s/\(\n\)\([+-]\{0,1\}[.][0-9]\{1,\}\),/\2|\1/
      s/\(\n\)\([+-]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\([.][0-9]*\)\{0,1\}\),/\2|\1/
      s/\(\n\)~\([0-9]*\),/\2|\1/
      s/\(\n\)\([0-9]*\)~,/\2|\1/
      s/\(\n\)~\([^~]*\)~,/\2|\1/
   /\n$/!bloop

   s/..$//
' $f
done
exit 0

Comment: @Sudheer What that means is that there are some fields which are not of the type being handled presently in the code. Providing a diagnostic facility within to help you zero in on the offender.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a dedicated CSV parser such as perl's [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

```
perl -MText::CSV -lne '
    BEGIN{ $csv = Text::CSV->new({ quote_char => "~" , escape_char => "~" , allow_whitespace => 1}) } 
    print join "|", $csv->fields() if $csv->parse($_)
  ' file_name
364034|2015652205|26722|2015|4|C25753-4|TC25753,|2WD Double Cab 144.2" SLT,|Y|40506.16|43555.00|1095.00|043,005,006,007,003,008,016,041,012,029,068,027,028,033|3|2WD Double Cab 144.2"|SLT|6|4|N|S|N|S|N|N|N|| |Confirmed|w2015k65m22t5|Sierra 2500HD|Double Cab Standard Box 2-Wheel Drive SLT|Rear Wheel Drive|Extended Cab Pickup - Standard Bed
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I can't use perl, I need to use standard unix shell scripting or unix commands.